# Trouble with launching PsychoPy2 in Windows 10

Tags: java, psychopy

I'm having trouble with launching PsychoPy, I tried to delete:

```
--> ${DOCS AND SETTINGS}\{USER}\Application Data\psychopy2\appData.cfg

--> ${DOCS AND SETTINGS}\{USER}\Application Data\psychopy2\userPrefs.cfg
```

But I can't find them in my computer data. Can anyone please help me?